# How to run mysql command from terminal?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, mysql

I have the following sql command which I usually run in phpmyadmin by selecting the database, then running it in the command window.

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "attachment"
```

However I've never done this via terminal before. My question is, how do I "point" this command to a specific database and then run it?

Comment: Try `mysql -u root -p`.

Comment: How can you run any command without login to MySQL? First in terminal you have to login using your MySQL `username` and `password` Eg: `mysql -uroot -p` then once loged in select your data base using `use <yourdatabasename` then you can run this command.

Comment: You can also put the database in front of the table like so: `DELETE FROM {databasename}.wp_posts WHERE `post_type` = "attachment"`

Comment: See also related question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1077725/295286

Answer (score 44):

For you to run it from terminal, you need to be logged into mysql first and then you execute your program. The ideal code would be

```
mysql -u(username) -p(password) (the name of the database) -e "DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "attachment""
```

I`m sure this works, hope it helps

Comment: You need to escape the backticks using \ if executing from a normal terminal

Comment: How about e.g. dropping a database and creating it again?

Answer (score 19):

I think you have forgot your user name for mySQL.
so please enter the correct user name and password when you type mysql command.
for eg

```
$ mysql   -u  root   -p 
Enter Password:
```

Note: Default user name and password  is `root`

Comment: Default root's access need sudo, `sudo mysql   -u  root   -p`

Comment: Default root's access need sudo, `sudo mysql   -u  root   -p`

Answer (score 10):

Just type the following command in terminal to use mysql interpreter:

```
mysql -u root -p database_name
```

Enter your password, then you can run your mysql commands.

Another way is to use:

```
mysql -u root -p database_name << eof
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "attachment"
eof
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
mysql --host *HOST_IP* --user *USER* --password=*PASSWORD* -D *DATABASE_NAME* -e "DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "attachment" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the MySQL CLI client.

```
$ mysql -u <user> -p
mysql> use <your-database>
mysql> DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "attachment"
```

Notice that I'm using `-u` and username, but in `-p` I'm not setting anything. MySQL will ask you for your password.

And if you're trying to use it inline, you can use

```
$ mysql -u <user> -p <your-database> -e "DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'attachment'"
```

Here, notice that I'm using also `-e` argument. It stands for *execute*.

**Pro tip**

In MySQL client you can use:

```
mysql> show databases;
```

if you want to view all dabatases in your server. And you can use:

```
mysql> use <database>;
mysql> show tables;
```

if you want to view all tables into a database.

I'm using `$` and `mysql>` as prompts, `$` means your Linux terminal, and `mysql>`, MySQL client.

Answer (score -1):

There is a series of steps to Execute MySQL in Linux Ubuntu Terminal.

1. Execute MySQL Client using the following command:
   `mysql -u root -p`
2. It is important to Create a New Database first using the command: 
   `create database demo_db;`
3. Then you have to Authorize the Database using the command: 
   `grant all on demo_db.* to ‘testuser’ identified by ‘12345’;`
4. Then Log in from the Database itself using the command: 
   `mysql -u testuser -p`
5. Then, you can actually start with the actual SQL Commands.

I referred to the article http://www.codingalpha.com/run-mysql-database-linux-ubuntu/ where they have explained perfect steps to Execute MySQL in Linux Ubuntu!
Hope I got your MySQL Running Perfectly.

Comment: Please note that `mysql` is the client, and not the server. Before starting the client, check that the server is running by issuing `sudo status mysql` and if it is not running, start it with `sudo start mysql`.

Answer (score -2):

Okay basically it was "SELECT databasename;" then executing my command.

Comment: You can also specify the database name on the command line, such as `mysql -u root -p databasename` - enter password when prompted and you are using the database.