# sh script for executing mysql script with entering pass

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, database, sh

I'd like to execute a mysql script where the user is asked to enter the password dynamically from the command line, if possible with a message `Enter your $root password`.
However it doesn't work as expected. So far I have

```
mysql -u root -p CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Test
```

moreover when the db is created how to logout from mysql and go back to bash commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html)

```
mysql -u root -p --execute="SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user"
```

prompts for a password, executes the given command, and returns to the shell (no logout required).

If you instead want your own prompt you need to script it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Enter pwd"
read pwd
mysql -u root -p$pwd --execute="SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user"
```

Please note that there must be no space between `-p` and `$pwd` because 
`mysql` then considers `$pwd` to be the database's name.

I would not recommend that because the password is then shown in 
cleartext in the terminal whereas `mysql -p` shows asterisks instead.

Answer (score 2):

Scripting MySQL queries can be done in couple of ways. [PerlDuck's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077730/295286) already touches on the `-e` or `--execute` parameter. Another way would be to use `source` command from MySQL itself to run an SQL script:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'source foo.sql'
Enter password:
+------+-------------+
| a    | b           |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | hello world |
+------+-------------+
$ cat foo.sql
use foo_db;
SELECT * FROM foo_tb;
```

Another way is to redirect the script into `mysql`'s `stdin`:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p < foo.sql
Enter password:
a   b
1   hello world
```

Note the difference in formatting in each case. Of course you can also use [here-doc or herestring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/678919#678919) to achieve same results, although using a text file allows executing lengthy queries, while here-docs and here-strings are more useful for moderately short statements.