# Backup of mysql database using terminal

Tags: mysql

I have use Ubuntu 14.04, in mysql, not able to login through phpmyadmin. So, i need to backup mysql database. How can i do this. any one help for this issues.

advanced thanks.

By
Udaya Kumar-PHP

Comment: Start with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341584/how-to-run-mysql-command-from-terminal), follow with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423654/export-dump-file-from-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

That is easily done by going to a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and typing:

For a single database:

```
mysqldump -u szUserName -p szDatabaseName > /path/to/file
```

For multiple databases:

```
mysqldump -u szUserName -p --databases szDatabaseName1  szDatabaseName2 szDatabaseName3 > /path/to/file
```

For all databases:

```
mysqldump -u szUserName -p --all-databases > /path/to/file
```

Where `szUserName` is obviously *your username*, `szDatabaseName1` is *your database name and `/path/to/file` is the path to the export file E.G. `./dump/db_backup.sql`

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **;-)** You just received an edit *and* your first upvote! **0:-)**  Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1153508/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**